# How to code a nested ordered list within an unordered list item?

Tags: html

I want to nest an ordered list within a single unordered list item, such that the ordered list splits up the text of the list item. For example:

• An unordered point, text text text...

1. First ordered list item

2. Second ordered list item

...continued text from same unordered point.

• Another unordered point

I'm wondering what's the proper way to code this? I've tried:

```
<ul>
  <li>An unordered point, text text text...
  <ol>
    <li>First ordered list item</li>
    <li>Second ordered list item</li>
  </ol>
  ...continued text from same unordered point.</li>
  <li>Another unordered point</li>
</ul>
```

but not sure if that's the correct way to mark it up. Also, when I testing this in Chrome and FF, the line spacing before and after the nested ordered list does not balance out; I'm getting:

• An unordered point, text text text...

1. First ordered list item

2. Second ordered list item

...continued text from same unordered point.

• Another unordered point

Comment: I see no problem with that.  http://jsfiddle.net/YbntS/  I'm not sure what you mean by "not balanced out".

Comment: @JamesMontagne: I mean there's more line spacing beneath the ordered list than above it. I guess the problem will be corrected with CSS, as per Matt K's suggestion. But it's interesting that it renders without the spacing problem in JSFiddle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the correct way, however you will need to play with the css to remove the margins on your nested list, which will fix your spacing problem.