# How to properly embed unordered lists within ordered lists (HTML)

Tags: html, css

So, I have an ordered list that has an unordered list within it, like so:

```
    <ol>
        <li>Choose which type of game you want to play</li>
        <li>Press the spacebar to start the game</li>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>Controls for single player mode:</li>
                <li>
                    <ul>
                        <li>W and S</li>
                        <li>&uarr; and &darr;</li>
                        <li>A and Z</li>
                        <li>' (apostrophe) and / (forward slash)</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Controls for double player mode:</li>
                <li>
                    <ul>
                        <li>The right player uses A and Z</li>
                        <li>The left player uses ' and /</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ol>
```

Unfortunately, it outputs this:

[image]

I embedded the additional `li`s as otherwise it failed W3C validation.  The Validator complained about sticking `<ul>` elements inside of `<ol>` elements otherwise.

***How do I fix this so that the list symbols in front of the items will go away?***

Comment: You want like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/3tphdb7r/)? Related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8747992/how-to-code-a-nested-ordered-list-within-an-unordered-list-item.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just don't create a new `li` to embed your nested `ul`s, but add them to the existing `li`. Like this:

```
<ol>
    <li>Choose which type of game you want to play</li>
    <li>Press the spacebar to start the game
        <ul>
            <li>Controls for single player mode:
                <ul>
                    <li>W and S</li>
                    <li>&uarr; and &darr;</li>
                    <li>A and Z</li>
                    <li>' (apostrophe) and / (forward slash)</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Controls for double player mode:
                <ul>
                    <li>The right player uses A and Z</li>
                    <li>The left player uses ' and /</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Since ordered and unordered lists are [block-level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) in HTML, they will wrap to the next line by default, so there's even no need to create additional `div`s or insert line breaks.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want? You put nested lists inside of the li:

```
<ol>
    <li>Choose which type of game you want to play</li>
    <li>Press the spacebar to start the game</li>
    <li>Controls for single player mode:
        <ul>
            <li>W and S</li>
            <li>&uarr; and &darr;</li>
            <li>A and Z</li>
            <li>' (apostrophe) and / (forward slash)</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Controls for double player mode:
        <ul>
            <li>The right player uses A and Z</li>
            <li>The left player uses ' and /</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ol>
```